# Find array/variable after getting HTML5 data attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

How do I find an existing declared array or variable after I get the value of a data attribute?

For example

```
var myArray = [{a: 50, b: 70}, {a: 80, b: 90}],
    mySecondArray = [{a: 30, b: 20}, {a: 80, b: 40}];

$('.button').click(function() {
    var newArray = $(this).data('value'); // this will be a string depending on the value of any .button i clicked on <div data-value='myArray'></div>

    doSomething(newArray);
};
```

How do I use HTML 5 attribute to find an existing array and do something to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest making an object with the two arrays as properties. This makes it easy to lookup the array that you want.

```
 var arrays = {
     myArray:[{a: 50, b: 70}, {a: 80, b: 90}],
     mySecondArray:[{a: 30, b: 20}, {a: 80, b: 40}]
 }

 $('.button').click(function() {
     var newArray = $(this).data('value'); 

     doSomething(arrays[newArray]);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't (without deprecated hacks).

However, you can store your accessible data in a map

```
var data = {myArray: [...], mySecondArray: [...]};
```

and look the values up via

```
doSomething(data[$(this).data('value')]);
```

**Example:**

```js
var myArray = [{a: 50, b: 70}, {a: 80, b: 90}],
    mySecondArray = [{a: 30, b: 20}, {a: 80, b: 40}];

var data = {myArray, mySecondArray};

$('.button').click(function() {
    var newArray = $(this).data('value');
    
    //console.log(window[newArray]); // hack - don't do it
    //console.log(eval(newArray));   // hack - don't do it
    console.log(data[newArray]);     // good
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" data-value="myArray">Click</button>
```

Why not `window[newArray]`? Because it only allows lookup of variables declared via `var` in global scope.

Why not `eval(newArray)`? See [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)